# ngrx EffectsModule - Need assistance in understanding providers usage

Tags: angular, ngrx-effects

I am trying to understand the use of provider factory in Angular.
I understand the examples provided in [Angular Documentation](https://angular.io/api/core/FactoryProvider).

However, I have encountered a rather unusual usage of provider factory in [ngrx EffectsModule (effects_module.ts)](https://github.com/ngrx/platform/blob/master/modules/effects/src/effects_module.ts).

```
@NgModule({})
export class EffectsModule {
  static forFeature(featureEffects: Type<any>[]): ModuleWithProviders {
    return {
      ngModule: EffectsFeatureModule,
      providers: [
        featureEffects,
        {
          provide: FEATURE_EFFECTS,
          multi: true,
          deps: featureEffects,
          useFactory: createSourceInstances,
        },
      ],
    };
  }

  // *** <snip> forRoot method for brevity

}
export function createSourceInstances(...instances: any[]) {
  return instances;
}
```

I understand the purpose of `multi:true`.

However, I am having hard time to figure why would `featureEffects` be declared as providers, and as well be used as dependency for `FEATURE_EFFECTS` - and what does `createSourceInstances(...instances: any[])` achieve?

What is this pattern and where can one use it?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Let's start with `@ngrx/effects` [documentation](https://github.com/ngrx/platform/tree/master/docs/effects).

The first thing we need to do is to create an `AuthEffects` service

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthEffects {
  @Effect()
  ...

  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private actions$: Actions) {}
}
```

How do we register effects?

It's easy:

```
EffectsModule.forRoot([AuthEffects])
```

or

```
EffectsModule.forFeature([AuthEffects])
```

Now, let's stop here and think what is the `AuthEffects`.

`AuthEffects` is just ordinary angular service that can have any dependencies(`HttpClient` and `Actions` in this case) that will be resolved with the help of Angular DI system.

And this service we are passing to the `EffectsModule` and also we can create more effects:

```
EffectsModule.forFeature([AuthEffects, MySecondEffects, ...])
```

---

Now, let's imagine that we're authors of `EffectsModule`.

We gave users the opportunity to provide any count of effects just by creating angular service. We're going to [use](https://github.com/ngrx/platform/blob/2cb81d8e2d522fbcfcea93bbed7a875bbb278473/modules/effects/src/effects_root_module.ts#L33) these services in our library:

```
addEffects(effectSourceInstance: any) {
    this.sources.addEffects(effectSourceInstance);
}
```

And as you can see we need to have instances of our provided services not only classes.

How can we create these instances?

Maybe like this?

```
EffectsModule.forFeature([new AuthEffects(new HttpClient(...), new Actions(...))])
```

Of course not! We can let angular DI to do that:

```
EffectsModule.forFeature([AuthEffects])
...

forFeature(featureEffects: Type<any>[]) {
  ....
    providers: [
        featureEffects,
```

Now Angular DI knows all these services and how to create them. But i as author also want to use them in my services but i don't know how to get them...

```
@NgModule({})
export class EffectsFeatureModule {
  constructor(
    // i need to get all effects provided by users but they are hidden in DI system
    ...
  ) {

  }
}
```

Fortunately, we can provide a token that will be used internally and will be known by the author of library.

For that we're [creating](https://github.com/ngrx/platform/blob/2cb81d8e2d522fbcfcea93bbed7a875bbb278473/modules/effects/src/tokens.ts#L9) InjectionToken:

```
export const FEATURE_EFFECTS = new InjectionToken<any[][]>(
  'ngrx/effects: Feature Effects'
);
```

and defining recipe for `FEATURE_EFFECTS` token:

```
  featureEffects,
  {
    provide: FEATURE_EFFECTS,
    multi: true,
    deps: featureEffects,
    useFactory: (...instances: any[]) => {
       return instances;
    },
  },
```

`multi` tells us that this token can be defined several times (i.e. we have several `forFeatures` calls)

`deps` specifies that `FEATURE_EFFECTS` token will use all `featureEffects` **instances** that will be created by Angular DI.

`useFactory` takes these instances as parameter.

This way we know exactly that injection `FEATURE_EFFECTS` token gives us all instances of effects.

Let's think if we could omit `featureEffects`, for example:

```
{
  provide: FEATURE_EFFECTS,
  multi: true,
  useValue: featureEffects
},
```

If we do so then we won't get instances but rather array of classes(functions). But we need to have all **instantiated** classes and only Angular DI is the best friend here.

And finally, although Angular DI is quite powerful pattern, it also has some restrictions.

In AOT the following code:

```
  featureEffects,
  {
    provide: FEATURE_EFFECTS,
    multi: true,
    deps: featureEffects,
    useFactory: (...instances: any[]) => {
       return instances;
    },
  },
```

will result in the error:

> Function expressions are not supported in decorators in
>   'EffectsModule'
>   Consider changing the function expression into an exported function.

So that's why it's written as follows:

```
providers: [
  featureEffects,
  {
     provide: FEATURE_EFFECTS,
     multi: true,
     deps: featureEffects,
     useFactory: createSourceInstances,
   },
],
...
export function createSourceInstances(...instances: any[]) {
  return instances;
}
```

And we can successfully get these instances [inside the library](https://github.com/ngrx/platform/blob/2cb81d8e2d522fbcfcea93bbed7a875bbb278473/modules/effects/src/effects_feature_module.ts#L10):

```
@NgModule({})
export class EffectsFeatureModule {
  constructor(
    ...
    @Inject(FEATURE_EFFECTS) effectSourceGroups: any[][],
...
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation.  I knew that it will take bit of effort to explain this question - and I am glad and thankful that you took time to put it with such clarity.